# Spring Securitiy: Retrieving data from custom user

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to add additional attributes to `Principal` object in `Spring Security`. Therefore I implemented

- CustomUser object which implements `UserDetails`
- CustomUserService which implements `UserDetailsService`.

**CustomUser:**

```
@Entity
public class CustomUser implements UserDetails { ... }
```

**CustomUserService:**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserRepository customUserRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        CustomUser customUser = this.customUserRepository.findByUsername(username);

        return new User(customUser.getUsername(), customUser.getPassword(), true, true, true, true,
            customUser.getAuthorities());
    }
}
```

Finally, I added this to my **security.xml:**

```
<beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="project.service.CustomUserService"></beans:bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

Now I want to retrieve some CustomUser specific attributes (e.g. fullName) via

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
CustomUser user = (CustomUser) auth.getPrincipal();
```

but I'm always getting a `ClassCastException`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to project.entity.CustomUser
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this? My goal is to get specific user data in a controller after a user was logged in successfully. Until now everything is working fine except retrieving CustomUser attributes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `CustomUser implements UserDetails`

But you are returning new User(...) and casting to CustomUser which is a type mismatch ,hence you got ClassCastException. 
You have to return directly CustomUser type as below.

```
   @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        return this.customUserRepository.findByUsername(username);
```

EDIT: 
Instead of CustomUser implements UserDetails, you have to extend User object and fill the details and return it as below. And you can separate UserEntity object and CustomUser object also

```
public class CustomUser extends org.springframework.security.userdetails.User {.....}

@Entity
public class UserEntity {...}

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

 UserEntity userEntity = this.customUserRepository.findByUsername(username);

 CustomUser customUser = new CustomUser( userEntity.getUsername(), userEntity.getPassword()........);

 return customUser;
}
```

After this you access

```
 CustomUser customUser = (CustoomUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I actually know that but when I return CustomUser my login doesn't work anymore... that's why I've returned org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User... . Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Solved it! Thank you so much!